# YII model ::: CGridView Search by specific attribute using criteria

Tags: php, yii-extensions, yii

I am new in yii. I want to search by attribute (field name) from my model and need to view in view page or another page by zii.widgets.grid.CGridView.

1. how can I create a search() function in model by findByAttribute()
2. so that we can show the results by attribute  without any search

here is my model function but it is not working.. :: ERROR Undefined variable: pp_requisitionno

```
    public function searchView()
{

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select= 'pp_requisitionno';
    $criteria->addSearchCondition('pp_requisitionno',$pp_requisitionno);
    $criteria->compare('pp_requisitionno',$this->pp_requisitionno);
    $criteria->condition = 'pp_requisitionno=:pp_requisitionno';
    $criteria->params = array(':pp_requisitionno'=>Yii::app()->Request->Getpost('pp_requisitionno'));
    $model = Requisitiondt::model()->find();
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Any help please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably going to be more useful to define a general search function that can be reused for different searches. This can be done in the following way:

```
/**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search() {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
//Define all your searchable fields here
        $criteria->compare('t.title', $this->title, true);
        $criteria->compare('t.type', $this->type, true);
        $criteria->compare('t.published', $this->published, true);
        $criteria->compare('category.id', $this->category_id, true);
//Add any other criteria, like the default sort order etc.

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }
```

Then in your controller you can use the search like this;

```
pubic function actionSearch(){
$model = new Requisitiondt;
if (isset($_POST)){
$model->attributes = $_POST;
$dataProvider = $model->search();
$this->render('searchView', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));
}
}
```

The view 'searchView' then looks like this;

```
<?php
$this->widget('CGridView', array(
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => array(
//Add in whatever columns you want the grid to show
)
));
?>
```

Obviously you'll need to replace your own model names and field names, but this is the general idea. This way will search for any attributes you include in the POST request,and is more reusable.

Comment: How can I show the results for specific attribites "type" per your answer ?? Please help me

Comment: This is a general example copied from an existing project I'm working on. You will need to substitute your won filed names, so, for example, where I've put t.type, t.published and t.title you will need to put in your own field names, e.g. t.pp_requisitionno.

Comment: @SelimReza edited my answer to add the view file. You can just use it like a normal CGridView

Comment: where I will use controller ?? please

Comment: You do have a controller to render the view file? Put it in there @SelimReza

Comment: it is not working somehow. Could you please provide me the perfect code if you do not mind. thanks

Comment: @SelimReza I'm sorry but I'm do not intend writing your code for you. If you're struggling with the concepts of controllers, widgets and views, then you perhaps need to work through some of the examples in the excellent Larry Ullman series of tutorials http://www.yiiframework.com/tutorials/, and gain a basic understanding of how Yii works before moving on to more complicated things. It's what I did when I started out.

Comment: Thanks you so much ... I will let you know the update

Answer (score 0):

You need use Relations in your model, read [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr).

Then add `'filter' => $model,` in your GridView Widget options array